# Redirect router react onClick not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I don't know what I am doing wrong with react route but it is not working as expected. Can you help me?

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
const AddUserNote = (props) => {
  const redirectOnClick = () => {
    return <Redirect to="/addNote" />
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=>redirectOnClick()}>Click Redirect</button>
    </div>
  )
}
export default AddUserNote
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
const AddUserNote = (props) => {
  const redirectOnClick = () => {
    props.history.push('/addNote');
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={redirectOnClick}>Click Redirect</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Difference** between Redirect and History

Rendering a `Redirect` will navigate to a new location. The new location will override the current location in the history stack.

`push()` function Pushes a new entry onto the history stack

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me why Redirect not working?

Comment: @HaiTien check solution and if it's helpful please accept/vote for this.

Comment: @akhtarvahid But you still did not explained why `<Redirect />` is not working.